# Bootstrap 3 button group: corner radius disappears after a button is hidden

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have the following Bootstrap 3 button group:

```
<div class="btn-group">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Left</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Middle</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Right</button>
</div>
```

I hide the first button using:

```
$("button:eq(0)").hide();
```

The result is that the first visible button doesn't have corner radius:

> [image]

I guess the BS says: *first child of .btn-group has border-radius* instead of *first **visible** child of .btn-group has border-radius*

Is there any way to fix this?

[**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Z2TWe/)

Note that I don't want to remove the button but to hide it.

Comment: Remove the element all together? I'm not sure if that would work, but like your visibility theory, that could be an option

Comment: @GerbenJacobs I want only to hide the button.

Comment: Yep, but that won't work. If you remove and add the button, it will work.

Comment: are you still looking for a better solution to this? I think I could come up with something involving (n) buttons. let me know!

Comment: @ambe5960 Sure! Post it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Given that you are already using jQuery, you could use the following to add a class to the first/last visible button elements.

```
$(".btn-group button:visible")
    .first()
    .addClass('radius-left')
    .end()
    .last()
    .addClass('radius-right');
```

[**EXAMPLE HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/rsT63/)

You would then need to add the following styling:

```
.btn-group > .btn.btn-default.radius-left {
    border-top-left-radius: 4px!important;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 4px!important;
}
.btn-group > .btn.btn-default.radius-right {
    border-top-right-radius: 4px!important;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 4px!important;
}
```

Unfortunately, `!important` is necessary to overwrite the default Bootstrap styling.

---

As an alternative, you could remove the first button element completely and then add it back in when necessary.. `$("button:eq(0)").remove();` -- [(example)](http://jsfiddle.net/LcvWz/)

Comment: This is only a particular solution. Imagine there are *n* buttons. If I hide the last one the your example will not work. Also, things get complicated when I hide more buttons.

Comment: +1, this solution works. Still waiting for a cleaner one. If there is not better solution I will mark your answer. Thanks!

Comment: seems not working fine on Apple's Safari also on every mobile iOS device :( see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28574134/strange-behaviour-of-safari-in-interpreting-css-selector-visible

Answer (score 1):

### AngularJS solution

*For pure jQuery projects, Josh Croziers answer is correct.*

But if you happen to be using AngularJS, there is a much simpler solution:

Add an `ng-if="expression"` to the button. When `expression` is true, the button will be shown, otherwise it will be removed from the DOM completely. This makes the "new" first button have rounded corners, because the `:first-child` selector that Bootstrap uses now selects that one.

Answer (score 0):

A **pure CSS** workaround which may be an acceptable solution is to put curved ends onto the btn-group itself using :before and :after pseudo-selectors so we don't end up with a border around the whole thing. Obviously, this won't apply the corner-radius directly to your buttons (as requested) but it can look good when your buttons aren't all different colours.

**NOTE**: you will either ALWAYS require hidden buttons at the start and end (to square the edges), or more reasonably, remove the radius from the btn-group CSS.

[Here's a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mmarlow/8r206s3c/1/), or check the snippet below.

```css
.btn-group{
  margin:20px; /* just for the demo */
}

.btn-group:before,.btn-group:after{
  display:block;
  float:left;
  content:".";
  color:transparent;
  /* WARNING: 
  Matching the bootstrap rules here, this can change when size rules (sm,xs) are applied to buttons 
  */
  padding: 6px 3px;
  font-size: 14px;
  border:1px solid #ccc;
}

.btn-group:before{
  border-radius: 4px 0 0 4px;
  border-right:none;
}

.btn-group:after{
  border-radius: 0 4px 4px 0;
  border-left:none;
}

/* WARNING: hard-coding bootstrap colour values, for demo-purposes, not recommended */
.btn-group.primary:before,.btn-group.primary:after{
  background-color:#337ab7;
  border-color:#2e6da4;
}

/* WARNING: hard-coding bootstrap colour values, for demo-purposes, not recommended */
.btn-group.info:before,.btn-group.info:after{
  background-color:#5bc0de;
  border-color:#46b8da;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="btn-group">
  <a href="#" class="btn btn-default hidden">One</a>
  <a href="#" class="btn btn-default">Two</a>
  <a href="#" class="btn btn-default">Three</a>
  <a href="#" class="btn btn-default">Four</a>
  <a href="#" class="btn btn-default hidden">Five</a>
</div>


<div class="btn-group">
  <a href="#" class="btn btn-default hidden">One</a>
  <a href="#" class="btn btn-success">Two</a>
  <a href="#" class="btn btn-danger">Three</a>
  <a href="#" class="btn btn-warning">Four</a>
  <a href="#" class="btn btn-default hidden">Five</a>
</div>

<div class="btn-group primary">
  <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary hidden">One</a>
  <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Two</a>
  <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Three</a>
  <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Four</a>
  <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary hidden">Five</a>
</div>

<div class="btn-group info">
  <a href="#" class="btn btn-info hidden">One</a>
  <a href="#" class="btn btn-info">Two</a>
  <a href="#" class="btn btn-info">Three</a>
  <a href="#" class="btn btn-info">Four</a>
  <a href="#" class="btn btn-info hidden">Five</a>
</div>
```